# How can I create VM using my custom Image on Azure?

Tags: azure, vhd, azure-image

I have a problem with starting a VM on Azure using my custom image.

**How I prepared my custom image:**

1. I had a VM running, based on an image from the Azure Marketplace.
2. I stopped that VM and exported the OS disk (downloaded the VHD file).
3. I uploaded that VHD file as a BLOB to my storage account on Azure.
4. I created a new image (Images -> Create), selecting the previously uploaded VHD file as "Storage Blob."

**Starting VM by UI**

1. When I try to create a new VM using my custom image through the Azure Web UI, the deployment fails with the following error message:

```
    {
      "code": "ResourceDeploymentFailure",
      "message": "The resource write operation failed to complete successfully, because it reached terminal provisioning state 'Failed'."
    }
```

**Starting VM by Azure Golang SDK**

1. When I try to launch a VM from the code level and I fill the `armcompute.VirtualMachineProperties` with image ID:

```
            StorageProfile: &armcompute.StorageProfile{
                ImageReference: &armcompute.ImageReference{
                    ID: to.Ptr("/subscriptions/MY_SUBSCRIPTION/resourceGroups/MY_RESOURCE_GROUP/providers/Microsoft.Compute/images/MY_IMAGE_NAME"), 
                },
```

to execute `VirtualMachinesClient.BeginCreateOrUpdate` method, I receive the following error:

> Creating a virtual machine from Marketplace image or a custom image sourced from a Marketplace image requires Plan information in the request

Does this mean that I always need to remember on which Marketplace image my custom image is based? I was planning to create several different custom images based on VMs running on various systems, and I thought that later, to use such images, only the Image ID would be sufficient.

Of course, when I'm filling `Plan` field with some random values, there is an error:

> The offer with Offer ID 'YOUR_OFFER' was not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just create an image from a Marketplace VM and provide it with random offer details. Any image you create from a Marketplace VM, will have the same offer requirements the original VM had. Otherwise this would be a very easy way to get away with not paying for any licencing the original marketplace VM had. You can find details of how to provide the offer ID [here](https://samcogan.com/creating-vms-from-a-marketplace-image-that-needs-a-plan/).

Secondly, you can't just export an existing managed disk to a blob and then use that as an image to create new VMs. You need to go through a process of creating an image by following the steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/capture-image-resource?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5002404). Please note that this is a legacy approach and the better option is to use the [Azure Compute Gallery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/azure-compute-gallery?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5002404)